# How to introduce a younger sibling to programming?

Tags: ide

I built a PC with/for my *nine* year old brother a few months back.

I think he is smart enough to grasp the concepts of programming, but I think that the textbook introduction (putting text to the screen, reading text from the keyboard) is too dry to keep his attention. Visual Studio is certainly too overwhelming.

Is there a programming language or toolkit appropriate for this age range?

Comment: Try Python and an online instruction site like http://www.learnpython.org/

Comment: +1 because you're a good brother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) is fun for kids. So is Visual Basic, to an extent.